# Find element by.ID in headless Chromium, when running on AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I got my selenium chromeDriver running on lambda successfully, but I can't get it to find an element by.ID.
The script runs perfectly fine on my local machine. Why does it not work on AWS lambda?

The Script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def startDriver():
    options = Options()
    options.binary_location = '/opt/headless-chromium'
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--windows-size=1920,1080')
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server="direct://"')
    options.add_argument('--proxy-bypass-list=*')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--single-process')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')


    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
    return driver

DRIVER = startDriver()
```

```
    DRIVER.get(dashboard_url)
    time.sleep(10)
    cookieBox = Wait(DRIVER, timeout=20).until(lambda d: DRIVER.find_element(By.ID, 'tru_accept_btn'))
    cookieBox.click()
```

When ending the code after `DRIVER.get(dashboard_url)` I can succesfully return `DRIVER.title` So I know, the page is loading, but for some reason the element cannot be detected:

> [ERROR] TimeoutException: Message:
>   File "/var/task/nestfunctions/_nestfunctions.py", line 19, in login
> cookieBox = Wait(DRIVER, timeout=20).until(lambda d:
> DRIVER.find_element(By.ID, 'tru_accept_btn'))
> File "/opt/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py",
> line 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)